# How to align the '?' and ':' in a ternary expression in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

Say if I have an assignment like:

```
int type = e.isIntExpr()  ? 0 :
           e.isBoolExpr() ? 1 :
           e.isAddExpr()  ? 2 : 3;
```

Are there any configurations I can specify in Code Style to align the `?` and `:`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't sweat the small stuff! Other people probably won't be interested in maintaining this alignment when things get tough, so you may be wasting time on something irrelevant. By all means have a style guide, but maybe stick to the Oracle Code Style Guide.

Also, I'd suggest concentrating on readability so others can understand what you're doing. Consider this code, to me it is much clearer what the code is doing:

```
int type;

if (e.isIntExpr()) {
    type = 0;
} else if (e.isBoolExpr()) {
    type = 1;
} else if (e.isAddExpr()) {
    type = 2;
} else {
    type = 3;
}

return type;
```

Comment: Actually, the nested ternary operators solution is MUCH more clear. It's also an expression, in contrary to the "if" statement.